# Getting warning when using preg_grep() with PREG_GREP_INVERT

Tags: php

I get the warning "preg_grep() expects parameter 2 to be array" when I try to `preg_grep("/\w/", $name, PREG_GREP_INVERT)`.
What wrong with it.

Comment: `$name` isn't an array.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($name);` and show us the output ...  if it does not slap you in that face with whats wrong

Comment: What're you trying to achieve.

Comment: Oh! I find out that $name is a string XD. But how I should do if I want to check whether they are illegal words like '%' '/' ... in the string.

Comment: Sorry my mother language is not english. I'm talk about the words like % < > ? / * & kind of special words?

Comment: Special characters?

Comment: Yes, I want to check whether they are special charaters in a string.

Comment: Check or remove?

Comment: Check. Like "123%%%" contains special charactors and "123" is not.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `$name` needs to be an array.

Reading from the [preg_grep documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep) you can see the setup is as follows:

> preg_grep ( string $pattern , array $input [, int $flags = 0 ] )

It accepts a string, an array, and then an optional integer.

---

### Solution

Now that I have a clearer understanding of what you'd like to achieve, please see below.

**Check if special characters exist in a string:**

```
if(preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $name)) {

    // Special character has been found.

}
```

**Remove special characters from a string:**

```
$name = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $name);
```

**Check if a particular word exists in a string:**

Obviously in this scenario the `$haystack` is what you are looking in, and `$needle` is what you are looking for.

```
if(strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) // Word has been found.
```

**Check if string contains spaces or special characters:**

```
if(preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]/', $name)) {

    // Special character or space has been found.

}
```

Comment: Well it could be that it is a comment rather than an answer, just a copy of the manual page. A decent answer based on the questions lack of detail is basically impossible.

Comment: OP asked a question - `What wrong with it.`, I have answered. I fully intend to expand my answer to answer the OP's next question, which is why I have since asked for more information in the comments

Comment: Oh, thanks! So just need to use preg_match() and manually type out the word I want to find?

Comment: It won't find an exact word for you - it will let you know if the `$name` variable has special characters in it.

Comment: Please see updated answer.

Comment: How should I do if I want to add space in special characters? I tried \s and ' ', both don't work.

Comment: What do you mean by 'add space in special characters', you want to find a space in a string?

Comment: Yes, I want to find space in a string.

Comment: I use `if(preg_match('/\s[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $name))`. But it won't find space.

Comment: If you look at the last example on my answer, if you change the `$needle` to a space, e.g. `strpos($haystack, ' ')` then this would match a space.

Comment: But I want to find whether they are special characters and space in a string.

Comment: Another update for you - last example on my answer.

Comment: Oh thanks for your patient. It work, and the thing I want to find when I ask this question is [^] XD

Comment: You're welcome - If that's everything I'd appreciate it if you marked this answer as correct.